# MongoDB $nin otherDocument.array without downloading otherDocument

Tags: mongodb

I've been fighting with a query for awhile now in which I have to download a document from the database to construct my query and it's honestly slowing things down quite a bit as my service starts to get more and more requests. I was wondering if someone could help me optimize the query, or make it so I don't have to download the initial document.

I'm going to use Tinder as an example here, as it simulates the amount of items that could potentially be in this array, and why having a "swipedBy: []" array on each client to remove the initial download of the query seems like it would be inefficient, as the array could end up being hundreds of thousands of elements long, and will only grow over time.

So let's say that I have a field in my user's documents called "swipes" which is an array of firebase ids (strings) of the user's that they have interacted with, an example of this can be found below:

```
{
    _id: 'firebaseUid,
    swipes: [ 'firebaseUid_1', 'firebaseUid_2', 'firebaseUid_3' ]
}
```

I have a query that is supposed to select a user from the database that is not already in MY swipes array, currently this is how I have it done. (Javascript)

```
database.collection('users').findOne({ _id: myUserId }).then((document => {
    const query = {
        ...,
        $and: [
            { _id: { $ne: myUserId } },
            { _id: { $nin: document.swipes }
        ]
    }
});
```

This requires me to download the user document from the database, then pass the whole array back in as a query, which seems highly inneficient, when talking about tens, if not hundereds of thousands of array elements.

While the above query DOES work, I feel like there's a way this can be sped up, and my lack of knowledge in MongoDB is really attacking me here. I know for a fact I can do this in MySQL, but I don't know of any good (and affordable) MySQL services like mLab.

I've been fighting with a query for awhile now in which I have to download a document from the database to construct my query and it's honestly slowing things down quite a bit as my service starts to get more and more requests. I was wondering if someone could help me optimize the query, or make it so I don't have to download the initial document.

I'm going to use Tinder as an example here, as it simulates the amount of items that could potentially be in this array, and why having a "swipedBy: []" array on each client to remove the initial download of the query seems like it would be inefficient, as the array could end up being hundreds of thousands of elements long, and will only grow over time.

So let's say that I have a field in my user's documents called "swipes" which is an array of firebase ids (strings) of the user's that they have interacted with, an example of this can be found below:

```
{
    _id: 'firebaseUid,
    swipes: [ 'firebaseUid_1', 'firebaseUid_2', 'firebaseUid_3' ]
}
```

I have a query that is supposed to select a user from the database that is not already in MY swipes array, currently this is how I have it done. (Javascript)

```
database.collection('users').findOne({ _id: myUserId }).then((document => {
    const query = {
        ...,
        $and: [
            { _id: { $ne: myUserId } },
            { _id: { $nin: document.swipes }
        ]
    }
});
```

This requires me to download the user document from the database, then pass the whole array back in as a query, which seems highly inneficient, when talking about tens, if not hundereds of thousands of array elements.

While the above query DOES work, I feel like there's a way this can be sped up, and my lack of knowledge in MongoDB is really attacking me here. I know for a fact I can do this in MySQL, but I don't know of any good (and affordable) MySQL services like mLab.

---

**I should add:** My MongoDB database is remote, so this document and massive array is being downloaded (per-request) to my Google Cloud Functions call, then being sent back to the server over the network. Meaning the data has to be downloaded and then uploaded over the network again, and considering I'm charged by the millisecond, I'd like to minimize that.

Comment: Something like `database.collection('users').findOne({ $or:[{_id: myUserId }, {_id: { $ne: myUserId, $nin: document.swipes }}]}`

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor swipes from user document to separate collection that point to the user who swiped and who was swiped. Also, this would enable to store additional data like was swiped left or right, timestamp and so on.

Comment: This answer is incomplete without showing how to do a cross-collection query against the data. We don't actually do "Swiping" in our application, it was just an example to demonstrate array size scale, the only thing that matters is the user's id.

Comment: It depends what you want to query. For example you can populate the second collection into the first one. Or maybe you don’t need cross collection query. Depends what you want to show.